# ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['neg', 'pos'], dtype='<U3')

Tags: python, machine-learning, precision, precision-recall

I recieve this error while trying to obtain the recall score.

```
X_test = test_pos_vec + test_neg_vec
Y_test = ["pos"] * len(test_pos_vec) + ["neg"] * len(test_neg_vec)

recall_average = recall_score(Y_test, y_predict, average="binary")

print(recall_average)
```

This will give me:

```
    C:\Users\anca_elena.moisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:1030: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  if pos_label not in present_labels:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/PyCharmProjects/NB/accuracy/script.py", line 812, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:/PyCharmProjects/NB/accuracy/script.py", line 91, in main
    evaluate_model(model, train_pos_vec, train_neg_vec, test_pos_vec, test_neg_vec, False)
  File "G:/PyCharmProjects/NB/accuracy/script.py", line 648, in evaluate_model
    recall_average = recall_score(Y_test, y_predict, average="binary")
  File "C:\Users\anca_elena.moisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 1359, in recall_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\anca_elena.moisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 1036, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    (pos_label, present_labels))
ValueError: pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['neg', 'pos'],
      dtype='<U3')
```

I tried to transform 'pos' in 1 and 'neg' in 0 this way:

```
for i in range(len(Y_test)):
     if 'neg' in Y_test[i]:
         Y_test[i] = 0
     else:
         Y_test[i] = 1
```

But this is giving me another error:

```
    C:\Users\anca_elena.moisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py:181: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  score = y_true == y_pred
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:/PyCharmProjects/NB/accuracy/script.py", line 812, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:/PyCharmProjects/NB/accuracy/script.py", line 91, in main
    evaluate_model(model, train_pos_vec, train_neg_vec, test_pos_vec, test_neg_vec, False)
  File "G:/PyCharmProjects/NB/accuracy/script.py", line 648, in evaluate_model
    recall_average = recall_score(Y_test, y_predict, average="binary")
  File "C:\Users\anca_elena.moisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 1359, in recall_score
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "C:\Users\anca_elena.moisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py", line 1026, in precision_recall_fscore_support
    present_labels = unique_labels(y_true, y_pred)
  File "C:\Users\anca_elena.moisa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py", line 103, in unique_labels
    raise ValueError("Mix of label input types (string and number)")
ValueError: Mix of label input types (string and number)
```

What I am trying to do is to obtain the metrics: accuracy, precision, recall, f_measure. With `average='weighted'`, I obtain the same result: accuracy=recall. I guess this is not correct, so I changed the `average='binary'`, but I have those errors. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your `recall_average` method ?

Comment: `recall_average` is just a variable name

Comment: Sorry, I renamed the variable `recall_average` to `recall` when I posted this. Now I edited the post.

Comment: sorry, I mean `recall_score`.

Comment: Or it just contains the `.score` method of `model`.

Comment: They are from python import
`from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, auc, f1_score, recall_score, precision_score`

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut `recall_score()` is function from `sklearn`. As the OP is doing a binary classification, just set `pos_label='neg'` in the call to `recall_score()`.

Comment: @AChampion ok so this is working, but can you tell me why? Why `pos_label='neg'` and not `pos_label='pos'`

Comment: Because that is one of the 2 values you are trying to `recall_score` over... the other option is `pos_label='pos'` and probably the one you actually want for your case. You could have alternatively done: `[1]*len(test_pos_vec) + [0]*len(test_neg_vec)` and then you wouldn't need to do it.

Comment: Please post the content of `Y_test` and `y_predict`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
recall_average = recall_score(Y_test, y_predict, average="binary", pos_label="neg")
```

Use `"neg"` or `"pos"` as `pos_label` and this error won't raise again.

Comment: as recall and precision have two scores 
i) In terms of -ve value
ii) In terms of +ve value
So you need to pass one of these value in pos_label so that function can return score in terms of that pos label

Comment: Thanks this comment really add the reasoning why the answer works.

Comment: I am getting this error now ValueError: pos_label='neg' is not a valid label: array(['0', '1'], dtype='<U1'). I solved this using '0' instead of 'neg', It was given in my matrix

Comment: If you are arriving at this question and using `cross_validate` introduced in version 0.19, the `pos_label` parameter has been removed and moved instead to the `make_scorer` function, so you will need to create your scores with `make_scorer(recall_score, pos_label='pos')` to make it work.

Answer (score 11):

When you face this error it means the values of your `target` variable are not the expected one for `recall_score()`, which by default are **1 for positive case** and **0 for negative case** [This also applies to `precision_score()`]

From the error you mentioned:

```
pos_label=1 is not a valid label: array(['neg', 'pos']
```

It is clear that values for your positive scenarios is `pos` instead of `1` and for the negative `neg` instead of `0`.

Then you have two options to fix this mismatch:

- Changing the value default in the `recall_score()` to consider positive scenarios when `pos` appears with:

```
recall_average = recall_score(Y_test, y_predict, average="binary", pos_label='pos')
```

- Changing the values of the target variable in your dataset to be `1` or `0`

```
Y_test = Y_test.map({'pos': 1, 'neg': 0}).astype(int)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be "pos_label='pos' " with hyphens around the "pos"?

Comment: @Moritz yes! well spotted

Answer (score 0):

Indicate your positive class with `(pos_label=pos)`

So use:

```
Recall=recall_score(Y_test, Y_predict, pos_label='pos')
```

Answer (score 0):

`recall_average = recall_score(Y_test, y_predict, pos_label="no")`

pos_label has array of only `["yes","no"]`